# How to call constructor from Template Haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I have function (let's call it `mkSome`) which constructs some data type with Template Haskell. It has typical signature `Name -> Q [Dec]`.
Somewhere in its body I'm extracting constructors of another type with
pattern-matching:

```
case tyCons of
  DataD ctx nm tyVars mbKind cs derivs -> ...
```

Type of those constructors `cs` instantiates some class like this:

```
class MyClass a where
  specialValue :: a
```

So, I'm iterating over those `cs` but I want to skip one of them which is
equal to `specialValue`. Something like this:

```
[c | c <- cs, c /= specialValue]
```

Example:

```
data OtherData = A | B | C
instance MyClass OtherData where
  specialValue = C
$(mkSome ''OtherData) -- mkSome must skip C-constructor!
```

How to do this in Template Haskell's (with `Con` type: `c` is it) ? Sure, I can't simply call constructor to compare created value with a `specialValue` because it's AST node, not real constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely on how you want to use this expression. You can write e.g.

```
mkCons :: Name -> Q Exp
mkCons ty = do
  TyConI (DataD ctx nm tyVars mbKind cs derivs) <- reify ty
  let cons = ListE $ map (\(NormalC c _) -> ConE c) cs
  [| [c | c <- $(pure cons), c /= specialValue] |]
```

which is a splice whose result is the constructors of `ty` except `specialValue`.

But if you want to manipulate the resulting list within the splice (e.g. generate some code for all constructors except `specialValue`) then the situation is much more complicated. You'll need to have a nested splice which manipulates the result of the above splice:

```
mkSome :: Name -> Q Exp
mkSome ty =
  [| do e1 <- mapM lift $(mkCons ty)
        let mkD (ConE n) = DataD [] (mkName $ "Foo" ++ nameBase n) [] Nothing [] [] -- example function
        pure $ map mkD e1
    |]
```

Note also the use of `lift`; the result of `$(mkCons ty)` has type `[OtherData]` (in this case) but `lift` gives you the TH AST corresponding to those constructors.

Also note that the functions above use the `Eq`, `Lift` and `MyClass` instances of the given type. Due to the stage restriction, you have to define these instances in a seperate module than the use of the splice. So the following won't work:

```
module A where

import TH (mkSome)

data OtherData = A | B | C deriving (Lift, Eq)
instance MyClass OtherData where
  specialValue = C

$( $(mkSome ''OtherData) )
```

You must use it like so:

```
-- A.hs
module A where

data OtherData = A | B | C deriving (Lift, Eq)
instance MyClass OtherData where
  specialValue = C

-- B.hs
module B where

import TH (mkSome)
import A

$( $(mkSome ''OtherData) )
```

The result:

```
    mkSome ''OtherData
  ======>
    do { e1_adJ0 <- mapM
                      lift [c_adJ2 | c_adJ2 <- [A, B, C], (c_adJ2 /= specialValue)];
         let mkD_adJ1 (ConE n_adJ3)
               = DataD
                   [] (mkName $ ("Foo" ++ (nameBase n_adJ3))) [] Nothing [] [];
         (pure $ (map mkD_adJ1 e1_adJ0)) }


    (do { e1_adJ0 <- mapM
                       lift [c_adJ2 | c_adJ2 <- [A, B, C], (c_adJ2 /= specialValue)];
          let mkD_adJ1 (ConE n_adJ3)
                = DataD
                    [] (mkName $ ("Foo" ++ (nameBase n_adJ3))) [] Nothing [] [];
          (pure $ (map mkD_adJ1 e1_adJ0)) })
  ======>
    data FooA
    data FooB
```